# EF Core and a runtime-defined schema

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

**Disclaimer**

I've tried to look for an answer, but the solutions I found don't work for me.

**Situation**

I have an EF Core 2.2 project with a schema defined in a configuration file.

For instance, each user should have its own environment with data tables, migration table, etc. So there is a config file (not necessarily under version control), which defines the schema name.

**What fails**

When creating a migration, EFCore tools hardwire the schema name (whatever it is at the moment of running) to the snapshot and migration code.

I managed to create the migration table in the arbitrary schema.

```
services
   .AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt =>
       opt.UseSqlServer(
           cred.Database.ConnectionString,
           opt => opt.MigrationsHistoryTable(
               "__EFMigrationsHistory", cred.Database.Schema)));
```

But the data tables are still created in the schema defined at the time of running the Add-Migration tool.

**What's tried**

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(mSchema.Schema)
```

Does not seem to have an effect.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<>.ToTable(nameof(...), mSchema.Schema)
```

This (together with the previous code) makes the query to look for the table in the new schema.
I don't need to play with `IModelCacheKey`, as there is only one model at a time, so I didn't.

```
Remove schema parameters from migration CS file
```

I thought this would force EF Core to use the default schema specified above. Instead, the data tables were created in `dbo` schema.

**Update**

As it looks, the core of EFCore has no problem using multiple schemas. It is Add-Migration tool that generates the migration with a hardcoded schema. Ans for whatever reason the migration and the model definition are totally separated.

**Can somebody point me to the right direction?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anybody wonders - I found the solution. it involves injecting some code into the EF migration pipeline, like this.

In `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```cs
services
    .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
    .AddScoped<IMigrationsSqlGenerator, SchemaMigrationsSqlGenerator>()
    .AddScoped<MigrationsSqlGenerator, SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator>()
    .AddDbContext<AppDbContext>((serviceProvider, sqlOpt) =>
    {
        sqlOpt.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider)
              .UseSqlServer(
                  connectionString,
                  // Make sure thge migration table is also in that schema
                  opt => opt.MigrationsHistoryTable("__EFMigrationsHistory", yourSchema));
    });
```

And create a new class:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// A class injected into the SQL command generation
/// in order to replace the schema with the one we want.
/// </summary>
public sealed class SchemaMigrationsSqlGenerator : IMigrationsSqlGenerator
{
    #region Fields

    private readonly MigrationsSqlGenerator mOriginal;

    private readonly ISchemaStorage mSchema;

    #endregion


    #region Init aned clean-up

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for dependency injection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="original">Previously used SQL generator</param>
    /// <param name="schema">Where the schema name is stored</param>
    public SchemaMigrationsSqlGenerator(MigrationsSqlGenerator original, ISchemaStorage schema)
    {
        mOriginal = original;
        mSchema = schema;
    }

    #endregion


    #region IMigrationsSqlGenerator API

    /// <inheritdoc />
    /// <remarks>
    /// Overwrite the schema generated during Add-Migration,
    /// then call the original SQL generator.
    /// </remarks>
    IReadOnlyList<MigrationCommand> IMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(
        IReadOnlyList<MigrationOperation> operations, IModel model)
    {
        foreach (var operation in operations)
        {
            switch (operation)
            {
                case SqlServerCreateDatabaseOperation _:
                    break;

                case EnsureSchemaOperation ensureOperation:
                    ensureOperation.Name = mSchema.Schema;
                    break;

                case CreateTableOperation tblOperation:
                    tblOperation.Schema = mSchema.Schema;
                    break;

                case CreateIndexOperation idxOperation:
                    idxOperation.Schema = mSchema.Schema;
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException(
                        $"Migration operation of type {operation.GetType().Name} is not supported by SchemaMigrationsSqlGenerator.");
            }
        }

        return mOriginal.Generate(operations, model);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The code above forces the migrations to be executed in the schema injected with a trivial `ISchemaStorage` interface.

Comment: Hi, I've found your answer quite helpful. But for some reason, SchemaMigrationsSqlGenerator is not used by EF/DI unless I replace it like this:
sqlOpt.ReplaceService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator, SchemaMigrationsSqlGenerator>()
Did you experience something like this as well? I wouldn't mind using ReplaceService() if it worked, but for some reason I'm getting an error that DI cannot resolve one of other services passed to SchemaMigrationsSqlGenerator by DI/ctor.

Comment: Did you notice the `UseInternalServiceProvider` call?